# How to set up specific pages to full width in Wordpress using twenty fourteen theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I would like to have **some specific page full with** while **other pages keep their size**.

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 with Twenty Fourteen.

Comment: In the `Dashboard`, when editing or creating a page, change the Page Template to `Full Width`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm pretty new to WordPress and was not aware, that this could be so easily achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page editor, there is a panel called 'page attributes' on the right side.  There is a drop down menu labeled 'template'.  Select 'Full Width Page' from the drop down menu. Learn more about page templates here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates